# How to forward fill missing data while recording which year the interpolation comes from?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My data looks like the follows:

```
country series YR1990 YR1991 ... YR2018 YR2019
RUS     A       xxx    xxx        xxx   NaN
CHN     A       xxx    NaN        NaN   NaN
RUS     B       xxx    xxx        xxx   xxx
CHN     B       xxx    xxx        xxx   xxx
.       .
.       .
.       .
```

I need to fill in the missing values of 2019 using 2018, if 2018 data unavailable then 2017, if 2017 data unavailable then 2016... all the way to 1990. I was able to do that using `ffill`.

However, when I replace the value with the value from one of the previous years, I need to generate a new column called `fill_year` to record which year I used to fill in the missing value.

Ultimately, I want a dataset like this:

```
country series YR2019 fill_year
RUS     A       xxx    2018
CHN     A       xxx    1990
RUS     B       xxx
CHN     B       xxx    
.       .
.       .
.       .
```

I've tried method like this:

```
for row in wb_long.iterrows():
        for yr in yr_list:
                if wb_long.loc[row,['YR2019']] == "NaN":
                        wb_long.loc[row, ['YR2019']] = wb_long.loc[row, [yr]]
                        wb_long.loc[row, ['YR2019']] = yr
```

but I got `Series objects are mutable and cannot be hashed`

Comment: What are the columns data types? is performance an issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

Start from generating an auxiliary DataFrame:

```
rows = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    fill_year = row.last_valid_index()
    last_val = row[fill_year]
    rows.append([last_val, '' if fill_year == 'YR2019' else fill_year])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['YR2019', 'fill_value'])
```

Then overwrite *YR2019* column with the respective column from *df2* and
add *fill_value* column:

```
df.YR2019 = df.YR2019.combine_first(df2.YR2019)
df['fill_value'] = df2.fill_value
```

To test the above code I changed slightly you data sample

```
  country series YR1990 YR1991 YR2018 YR2019
0     RUS      A    x01    x02    x03    NaN
1     CHN      A    x04    NaN    NaN    NaN
2     RUS      B    x05    x06    x07    x08
3     CHN      B    x09    x10    x11    x12
```

and got the following result:

```
  country series YR1990 YR1991 YR2018 YR2019 fill_value
0     RUS      A    x01    x02    x03    x03     YR2018
1     CHN      A    x04    NaN    NaN    x04     YR1990
2     RUS      B    x05    x06    x07    x08           
3     CHN      B    x09    x10    x11    x12
```